# get_object_or_404 does not work on User model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

When I use:

```
post = get_object_or_404(Employee, user_id=User.objects.latest('id'))
```

It returns the latest employee, as Employee.user_id is foreign key to User.id

When I use:

```
post = get_object_or_404(User, id=User.objects.latest('id'))
```

I would expect to get the latest user, yet now I get the following error:

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'User'

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated:

> Employee.user_id is foreign key

It is a foreign key pointing to the `User` object.

Therefore, assigning it an object found with a query `User.objects.latest('id')` works fine. In the second case, the `id` parameter is an int(), not a foreign key, so you cannot assign it the `User` object. Try with it's `id` attribute:

```
post = get_object_or_404(User, id=User.objects.latest('id').id)
```

Comment: But there is absolutely no point doing this. The return value of this whole thing *is* `User.objects.latest('id')`. Why wrap it in another query that returns the same thing?